# An extra app pool auto created on IIS Server 10.0

Tags: iis, .net-core, application-pool

I am facing an issue with IIS Server 10.0, Window Server 2016.  I am using InstallShield to install a web application.  It is using a new .NET CORE application that uses an Unmanaged app pool.  The app pool is successfully created and assigned by the installer.  However, if any other web application is installed, the system creates a new managed app pool with the same name as the original prefixed with "ASP.NET v4.0", which kills the .NET Core app.

Any idea how I can prevent the creation of this extra app pool?

**UPDATE:**

Note that when an ASP.NET version of 4.0 is set for websites or applications, the InstallShield IIS functionality calls the .NET 4.0 version of aspnet_regiis.exe. When this tool runs, any existing application pools that are not set to use .NET 4.0 are duplicated, renamed to "ASP.NET v4.0 Existing name", and have their .NET framework versions set to v4.0.

Actually, this is happening. By Default, when I install my DotNet Core webapi, default app pool type is "No Managed Code". So, when I install another web application, IIS makes an extra app pool.

But, if I change my dotnet core webapi app pool to "ASP.NET V4", Another application will not create an extra app pool.

So, another question is "Should I not use "No Managed Code" app pool type for DotNet Core WebAPI?

Comment: any time a new site is created, it needs to be assigned an existing AppPool or create a new one for it. The Installer seems to be buggy if it creates a pool that effects an existing site.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf No, It's not a installer bug. Something else. I updated my question.

Comment: I don’t know InstallShield, but as far as I know, iis does not automatically create application pools. In addition, you need to set the .NET CLR Version to No Managed Code because the Core Common Language Runtime (CoreCLR) for .NET Core is booted to host the app in the worker process, not the desktop CLR (.NET CLR).